# I am facing an minCompileSDK issue while developing an android app using android studio

Tags: java, android

Below is the details of the issue
The minCompileSdk (31) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-30)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This exception is self-explanatory: `compileSdkVersion` in your manifest is lower than the version required by AarMetadata.

You may change the minimum version required by changing the `minCompileSdk` property (see docs here: https://developer.android.com/reference/tools/gradle-api/4.2/com/android/build/api/dsl/AarMetadata) or change the `compileSdkVersion` in your manifest